# Return destructed argument in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**Scenario**: I have an object that I want to save, before saving I want to an ID to the object and after saving return the object with it's ID.

Let's assume I have the following basic function:

```
let create = (someObj) => {
  if (!someObj.id)
    someObject.id = 'myNewIdForThisObject';

  ... // persisting happens here
  return someObj;
}
```

Now that works just fine, but some people are calling this function *not providing an object*, so I want to prevent that like so:

```
let mandatory = () {
  throw new Error('Missing argument');
}

let create = (someObj = mandatory()) => {
  if (!someObj.id)
    someObject.id = 'myNewIdForThisObject';

  ... // persisting happens here
  return someObj;
}
```

Ok so that is great, but now they do provide an object but with no name (I know, sad panda). So I can make the name property mandatory as well by destructing the argument:

```
let mandatory = () {
  throw new Error('Missing argument');
}

let create = ({name = mandatory()} = mandatory()) => {
 ...
}
```

That also means I can have the ID in the object like so:

```
let create = ({id = 'myNewIdForThisObject', name = mandatory()} = mandatory()) => {
  ... //persistence happens here
  // here I would like to return the parameter with it's ID
  // without rebuilding the object
}
```

What I would like to know is how do I return the destructed argument from the function without rebuilding the object inside the function.

I cannot simply return `arguments[0]`, because of the defaults being used it will **not** return what gets assigned, only what was passed in.

Is there a way to name the destructed object to simply return it?

Comment: Defaults don't assign anything in the object, they default-initialise the local variable! If you want to set the `.id` of the original object, you have to do so explicitly.

Comment: off topic it  is not possible in javascript but c# support this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think it's possible to use destructuring on an argument *and* give the argument a name. Does the following not work for you?

```js
let create = (someObj = mandatory()) => {
  const {id = 'myNewIdForThisObject', name = mandatory()} = someObj;
  someObj.id = id;
  return someObj;
}
```